# RabbitMQ Visibility Timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, queue, rabbitmq, amazon-sqs

Do RabbitMQ queues have a AWS SQS-like - "message visibility timeout"  ?

From the AWS SQS documentation :

"The visibility timeout clock starts ticking once Amazon SQS returns the message. During that time, the component processes and deletes the message. But what happens if the component fails before deleting the message? If your system doesn't call DeleteMessage for that message before the visibility timeout expires, the message again becomes visible to the ReceiveMessage calls placed by the components in your system and it will be received again"

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the RabbitMQ manual acknowledgment feature. This feature allows you get messages from the queue and once you have receive them ack'ed them. If something happens in the middle of this process, the message will be available again in the queue after a certain amount of time. Also, in the meantime since you get the message until you ack it, the message is not available for other consumers to consume.

I think this is the same behavior as Message Visibility Timeout of SQS.

Comment: yes, but how can you control the ammount of time. I need to make a message invisible for at most 12h.

Comment: I'm interested in this as well.  I'd like to change the visibility time to something greater than the default (which i think is 3 mins?)

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#acknowledgement-timeout is somewhat close, but does not work for my use case

Answer (score 4):

There aren't any message timeouts; RabbitMQ will redeliver the message only when the worker connection dies. It's fine even if processing a message takes a very, very long time.There aren't any message timeouts; RabbitMQ will redeliver the message only when the worker connection dies. It's fine even if processing a message takes a very, very long time.

Comment: That's superior to SQS in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer can be found @ [a discussion of MQ vs SQS](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Visibility-timeout-feature-td4525752.html) generally this is a considered a feature of MQ (that it can handle slow consumers) but using a destination policy of "slowConsumerStrategy" with "abortSlowConsumerStrategy" might solve your problem. A fuller explanation can be found at [redhat's MQ documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_a-mq/6.0/html-single/tuning_guide/index) and i supposed we have to hope that rabbitMQ and AmazonMQ both support that strategy.